# Spark - Is the built-in rdd.count() function reliable in a cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm currently writing a simple spark script that uses the rdd.count() function, and when I test it running locally it works great.

Will it continue to work when I deploy my code to a multi-machine cluster, or is this function vulnerable to distributed calculation issues?

Comment: Why would you think it won't work?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the documentation suggesting it would work in this specific case. However, there's quite a lot of documentation that suggests that accumulators are needed to synchronize counting operations performed on distributed machines, so I'm wondering if I should look into using those.

Comment: This is the purpose of any distributed framework : it *needs* to work in a multi-machine cluster. Thanks to Spark's fault tolerance architecture, you don't need to worry about any built in operators working or not in a cluster subjected to failures - they just do their job.

Answer (score 0):

It's just like a MapReduce wordcount... It distributes the partitions of the data, and sums the numbers.

So, to answer the question, it should work acceptably fine in a distributed environment.